Helmholtz free energy density proof
We see Helmholtz free energy density is given as $f(n,T)$, with $n = N/V$. (fig.2: DOI: 10.3390/e17074563, Solid States Notes, Hadley)
Given that Helmholtz free energy $F = E - TS$, is such that $dF=−SdT−pdV+\mu dN$, How to show that $F(T,V,N) = V f(n,T)$?
Basically, in a given question, we have to proof, $F(T,V,N) = Vf(n,T)$, $G(T,p,N) = Ng(p,T)$, $A(T,V,\mu) = Va(T, \mu)$. Then we use these to show that $de = Tds+ dn$ and $dp = nd\mu +sdT$.

Additivity with respect to extensive variables ($F(T, V_1 + V_2, N_1 + N_2 ) = F(T, V_1 , N_1 ) + F(T, V_2, N_2 )$ and continuity of the Helmholtz free energy imply it is a homogeneous function of degree 1 of its extensive variables. Therefore,
$$
F(T, \lambda V, \lambda N) = \lambda F (T, V, N)
$$
for every $\lambda >0$ and every $T$, $V$, and $N$.
In particular, we have the required proof by choosing $\lambda = 1/V$.

Thank you for help!
